# Nothing for innerHTML of div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use javascript to grab the innerHTML of an element.  The innerHTML is the results of a query ran.  Sometimes the query returns no data so there is nothing inside of the div.  I do an alert and it says '[object HTMLDivElement]'.  I need to account for this when there is no data for the innerHTML in an if statement.  Does anyone know how I would do this?  How would I write the IF part?

```
var HSA_EmployeeCont = document.getElementById('HSA_EmployeeCont').innerHTML;
//alert(HSA_EmployeeCont);

if (HSA_EmployeeCont == 'object HTMLDivElement') {
   ...
```

Comment: If there's nothing in the element it should be blank. Could you make a fiddle replicating this?

Comment: so how would I write the if?

Comment: `if (!HSA_EmployeeCont.length)`

Comment: I didn't -1, but I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `length` of the `innerHTML`:

```
if (!HSA_EmployeeCont.length)
    console.log("Nothing here!");
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (!HSA_EmployeeCont)` should do the trick.

Your alert should be showing nothing, perhaps you forgot to add `innerHTML` before you tested with an alert?